# How can i count a specific words in a certain string?

Tags: javascript

i'm new to javascript langguage and still learning some of the data types and i get execise which i can not comprehend, please help me.

The exercise question :

> 'Love is the best thing in this world. Some found their love and some are still looking for their love.' Count the number of word **love** in this sentence.

so i tried some of the basic method such as,

1. match
2. search
3. split

and i cannot count the words love and given love words index.

how can i code this to find the answers?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
let sentence = "Love is the best thing in this world. 
Some found their love and some are still looking for their love."

console.log(sentence.split("love").length)
```

Comment: This would return one more that the desired number : `"love blabla love blabla love".split("love").length` would return 4 instead of 3 (in the example it works because it doesn't match the first occurrence which is capitalized.)

Comment: okay, i get it 

this is really help me, thanks for your help 
i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const sentence = 'Love is the best thing in this world. Some found their love and some are still looking for their love.'
const occurrences = sentence.match(/love/gi); // (g is is for match all occurrences, i is for case insensitive)
console.log("number of occurrences of 'love'", occurrences.length)
```

Comment: when i tried in the console it gives me this types of error

VM9530:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ocurrences is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:48

Comment: Try now, ther ewas a typo, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

To make it a little more generic and to show of the use of reduce:

```js
const data = "Love is the best thing in this world. Some found their love and some are still looking for their love"

const dataArray = data.split(' ');

const wordMap = dataArray.reduce((result, word) => {
    result[word.toLowerCase() ]= result[word.toLowerCase() ] ? result[word] + 1 : 1;
    return result
}, {});

console.log(wordMap["love"])
console.log(wordMap["is"])
console.log(wordMap["best"])
```

Comment: what is reduce functions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex, also you can implement generic regex rules too.

```js
const count = (str) => {
  const re = /love/gmi
  return ((str).match(re) || []).length
}

console.log(count('Love is the best thing in this world. Some found their love and some are still looking for their love'))
```

Comment: Thank you this is new for me, can i get reference to using a regex?

Answer (score 0):

i have created a solution in Java in eclipse. I am not that programming genius but have a little experience for three years now.

public class Question {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String s = "Love is the best thing in this world. Some found their love and some are still looking for their love."; 
     String split[]=s.split(" "); //splits every char sequence to an array by space -> " "
    
     int i=0; //counting variable to run through the foor loop
     int count = 0;  //counting the matching char sequences

     for(i=0; i<split.length; i++) { //running the for loop from o until the end of the array length with the splitted strings
         System.out.println(split[i]); //helping output to see whats been splitted
         if(split[i].contains("Love")|| split[i].contains("love")) { // checking every array space if it contains the word Love or love (case sensitiv)
             count++; //if it matches count up by one
         }
     }
     System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

the added comments should explain what i have done in the task. Just look for the output in the console that should clear things up.

[The words are the content of the splittet string. The last output (3) is the counted amount of love](https://i.stack.imgur.com/606nP.png)

Regards Yannik

Comment: Thank you, is this also available in javascript, as i known public static void main is Java